# Retrieve cell towers information from a background service

Tags: android

1. I have been trying using TelephonyManager to get cell tower
   location, the Telephony manager object returns **null** when **I
   close my app.**
2. After closing app, when the background service runs the cellInformation object is null.

The code is (The service is called every 10 minutes to find location):

```
public class LocationDetector extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("Location", "Location detector started");
    getCellDetails();

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void getCellDetails() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        List<CellInfo> cellInformation = tm.getAllCellInfo();
        // get the list of the cell location for the top 3 in the list
        for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < 3; iCounter++) {
            CellInfo info = cellInformation.get(iCounter);

            if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                CellIdentityGsm identity = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellIdentity();
                Log.i("Location ", "Cell id: " + identity.getCid() + " Cell Location code: " + identity.getLac() + "Cell Operator: ");

            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                CellIdentityWcdma identity = ((CellInfoWcdma) info).getCellIdentity();
                Log.i("Location ", "Cell id: " + identity.getCid() + " Cell Location code: " + identity.getLac() + " MCC:" + identity.getMcc() + " MNC:" + identity.getMnc());

            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                CellIdentityLte identity = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellIdentity();
                Log.i("Location ", "Cell id: " + identity.getCi() + " Cell Location code: " + identity.getTac() + "Cell Operator: " + identity.getMobileNetworkOperator());
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e("Location", "Telephony object is null" + e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Location", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

The permissions are like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Permissions at runtime:

```
@TargetApi(23)
    private void askPermissions() {
        String[] permissions = {
                "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
                "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        };
        int requestCode = 200;
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }
```

Comment: Is the app granted the permissions on the runtime?

Comment: Yes, it also shows the cell id. location etc. when the app is running

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Location Services` in API level 26 or high (android 8.0 or above) to access cell info from the background.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. Solution I found was just to make sure app has permissions for getting location in the background.
"android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"
When user allows the location as "allow all the time", I get the cellinfo object filled.
Without the permission,we have data in the foreground but it returns NULL in the background.